# Ionic/Cordova: Can't trigger the iOS keyboard programmatically

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I want that the keyboard for iOS and Android devices, opens automatically after 1s when a specific textarea get's visible.

I created a `directive`, but the keyboard on iOS is not coming up! Is there a (new) problem, regarding the keyboard with iOS 10?

My `textarea` looks like:

```
<textarea rows="20" autocorrect="off" ng-trim="false" focus-me></textarea>
```

And the directive looks like:

```
app.directive('focusMe', function($timeout) {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      $timeout(function () {
        element[0].focus();
        if (window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard && ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
          window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard.show(); //open keyboard manually on android
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
  };
});
```

On Android and in the browser everything works as expected, but on iOS there is no reaction.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're missing to adding `ionic.Platform.isIOS()` how to condition inside of your directive.

Greetings.

Comment: Thanks. But iOS does not need the `window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard.show()` statement. If I call this function for iOS, Xcode warns that `element.focus()` is enough.

Comment: Is Some one worked on PJSIP ? I stucked on this from last month

Comment: You try with `native.keyboardshow`. Here you can find more information about this: [link](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard#nativekeyboardshow)

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to added this line in the config.xml?

```
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
```

Comment: Yes, I've added this line, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: This is the working answer.  Set your focus to your input field.  Sometimes a short delay will help.  like this:  setTimeout(function(){$('#toeditfield').focus();},500);

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an additional plugin to trigger the keyboard.  Just set .focus() to your input field, but add a short delay.  For iOS you also need to add the config option to config.xml

```
 setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('#editfield').focus();
 },500);
```

Add to config.xml for iOS:

```
 <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
```

This works for my iOS & Android apache cordova apps.  I'm compiling today with latest version Nov 12/2019.